# PlayFramework -- Look up actors in another local ActorSystem

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

I have a play application where some actors are located in another ActorSystem. I'm trying to access the actors in that ActorSystem from the play application (basically I connect them to a REST API, i.e. send them messages when the play app gets a POST).

I'm creating this ActorSystem at start and I can confirm from the logs that it's indeed starting.

Let's assume the path of an actor in this separate system is akka://my-system/user/my-actor. How do I send a message to that actor?

I tried:

```
Akka.system.actorSelection("akka://my-system/user/my-actor") ! SomeMessage(...)
```

But this doesn't work. In the logs, I can see the following error (with deadLetters logging enabled):

```
Message ... from Actor[akka://application/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://application/deadLetters] was not delivered
```

Why doesn't it work?? And how can I get it to work?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Akka.system is the "my-system" actor system, then you should be able to skip the "akka://my-system" part and go directly for "/user/my-actor".

If Akka.system is another actor system, then you can use remoting and specify a complete address to the other system, like this "akka.tcp://my-system@my-host:my-port/user/my-actor".

Comment: Thanks Björn! This is weird though. Can you then suggest a way to do what I have in mind without involving remoting? The point is to have a "core" system and then a lightweight "control" system on the side (i.e. as a separate actorsystem) deployed on the same machine. My point is: why is it forcing me to do remoting to localhost just because it's a different actorsystem...

Comment: There is no global registry of actor systems in Akka, so there is no way to look up my-system by name. On the other hand, if you expose the my-system actor system to the first actor system I think that you can do mySystem.actorSelection("/user/my-actor").

Comment: OK, makes sense I guess. From what I can read between the lines both in your answers and in the akka doc, it makes no sense to deploy two different actorsystem on the same host. Maybe the reason why this use case isn't supported is because I'm trying to map one actorsystem to do the processing and another separate system for the interface. To me that's an obvious use case. Apparently, the akka team hasn't though of it or maybe its architects have a better way to do what I'm trying to do. In any case, I'm accepting your answer. Hopefully some akka devs will take a look and give me their 2cts...

Comment: It makes perfect sense to deploy multiple actor systems, if you treat them as multiple actor systems, and the only "transparent" way is t treat them as systems talking over remoting. BTW I am an Akka dev ;)