# Akka -- Deploy two ActorSystems on the same host

Tags: scala, akka

I'm writing this as a follow up to [PlayFramework -- Look up actors in another local ActorSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815032/playframework-look-up-actors-in-another-local-actorsystem), but this time targetting the question specifically to the Akka crowd.

The question is simple: Does it make sense to deploy two ActorSystems on the same host (not just on the same host but even on the same JVM), given that there appears to be no way to simply lookup the other system through system.actorSelection unless you remote to localhost?

In other words, since system1.actorSelection("akka://system2/user/my-actor") does not work, but system1.actorSelection("akka.tcp://system2@127.0.0.1:2552/user/my-actor") does, why even consider deploying two systems?

I suspect you're going to ask about a use case, so here's one for you. Assume I have a complex real-time system using Akka and that this system is deployed as autonomous agents on any number of machines. Ideally, I'd like to have fine-grained control of the resources I allocate to this system and I'd like it to be somewhat isolated. Furthermore, assume that I want to write a small control interface (e.g., a REST API) with the specific purpose to provide input and monitor the real-time system. Naturally, I would make that control system another ActorSystem which interacts with the first system. It makes sense, right? I don't want to have actors running in the same ActorSystem as the real-time processing (for isolation, practicality, separate logging, non pollution of resource monitoring, supervision -- that would add one more branch to the hierarchy --, etc.). That control ActorSystem would never be deployed on a separate machine since it goes hand in hand with the real-time system. Yet, the only way for these two systems to communicate is through loopback tcp.

Is what I'm suggesting not the proper/intended way to do things? Am I missing something? Is there a way to do this that I haven't considered? Does my use case even call for using Akka?

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having two separate actor systems, you could have a top level actor for each of the branches and run each branch on a dedicated dispatcher. Each top level actor will have its own error kernel as well. Having 2 actor systems mostly makes sense, when they are not related, but as yours communicate, I would not separate them.

Comment: I second this proposal. Especially since you intend to run the two actor systems inside the same JVM, you won't get any extra isolation by splitting them into two actor systems.

Comment: I would second this solution if the systems run on the same JVM, otherwise I'd suggest two JVMs with independent systems that can be switched on and off, redeployed, and evolve independently. E.g. you could later decide to cluster differently the different systems.

Comment: If the two systems do not run on the same JVM the only way to communicate is using remoting, and the question becomes kind of moot ;-) From Björn's response I gather that the Akka team considers running multiple actor systems on one JVM a use-case they want to discouraged, therefore it makes sense that there is no way to make calls between them without using remoting. Every other scenario using multiple systems inherently needs remoting anyway.

Comment: OK, but what if I'd like these two ActorSystems to have different configurations? I get that isolation is out the window anyways since both systems are meant to communicate, but let's assume I want the control system to log elsewhere, or that I'd like to avoid the control system slowing down the real-time system if its becomes bursty. I get that it might be possible to do this within the same system, but it seems to me that the better way is to just have ActorSystems that are separated, each with its own config.

Comment: The slowing down issue can be handled with separate dispatchers. It would basically give you the same type of isolation as separate systems (you are after all running in the same JVM, and threads compete for CPU, Memory, and other resources). The logging can't be fixed easily though.